# Unable to install "Terminator" in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, terminator

I am trying to install "terminator" in ubuntu 12.04. But it returns this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

terminator: Depends: python (>= 2.5) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
    Depends: python-vte but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: python-gtk2 (>= 2.14.0) but 2.24.0-3 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 3):

`apt` may give you an older version, which may be incompatible, so to install the very latest Terminator:

```
sudo apt-get remove terminator

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-terminator
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

Source: [official terminator page's install instructions](http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get -f install`

If that doesn't work, do these:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install python`
3. `sudo apt-get install python-vte`
4. `sudo apt-get install python-gtk2`

If THAT doesn't work, download python-vte from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-vte and:

1. Open a console.
2. `cd ~/Downloads`
3. `sudo dpkg -i python-vte_0.28.2-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb`
4. `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install-vte`
then it returns
**E: Package 'python-vte' has no installation candidate**

others returns
**python-gtk2 is already the newest version** 
**python is already the newest version**

Comment: download deb from here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-vte

Comment: I have downloaded it and also extract. But I am not sure what I will do next. will please describe next step ?

Comment: edited answer...

Comment: `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-vte:
 python-vte depends on libvte-common (= 1:0.28.2-5ubuntu1); however:
  Version of libvte-common on system is 1:0.28.2-3ubuntu2.
dpkg: error processing python-vte (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-vte
`

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: if that doesn't work, you can't run terminator.